# Swiping through fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I'm building an application where i use a tabhost. In each tab there is a fragment, so the user can swipe through each fragment. I want different buttons in each fragment but them on the tabhost, so that they won't swipe too. So i change each button in the onTabChanged() method of the tabhost dynamically. But this results in slowing down, actually freezing for a bit. I even tried putting it on a thread but it didn't make any difference. Do you know any way that i can use so that the swiping through the screens will be smooth again?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try explaining a little bit more clearly. I can't figure out what exactly do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

your explanation is really fuzzy but as far as I understood what you want to do is to move the buttons to outside the tabhost and on the click event you use something like:

```
    switch(tabHost.getCurrentTab(){
        // do stuff 
    }
```